# Text stream processing in R

Tags: r, text-processing

Is it possible to process text stream in R similar to `awk` or `sed` in linux? The idea is to read in line by line, process and then write to file, without having to read in the whole file to memory.

Any examples or links to such an approach is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the `readLine` function can read a specified number of lines for an open connection.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is! You can use  `readLines()` which is a  part of the base package in R. You can import a text file, post a string or open a connecting to a webpage.
Check it out here:
[readLines in Cran](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html)

Comment: I am aware of readLines(), but I thought that would just read the indicated number of lines into memory. Can you provide an example, if any, that uses readLines() to read a text file, does a text process every line and outputs the results without first reading the whole file into memory?

Comment: You can set up a function that you create using `readLines()` to handle how you want to bring the text in and what to do with the lines as they arrive. You can open a connection to the file, set up a loop to read line by line, and use either REGEX or other r methods to manipulate the text and then save the file. It can accomplish what `awk` can, but not in the same grammar. You will need to write code to make it happen.